# Scala case match a String

Tags: scala

I'm trying to match case against a String and have the following code:

```
val selectedAnswers: List[Int] = questionType match {
  case "CHECK_BOX"    => {
    answerCheckBox match {
      case Some(answers) => answers
      case None => List()
    }
  }
  case "RADIO_BUTTON" => {
    answerRadio match {
      case Some(answer) => List(answer)
      case None => List()
    }
  }
  case _ => {
    List()
  }
}
```

Why is it not falling through the _ case when the String is not RADIO_BUTTON or CHECK_BOX?

The values for answerRadio and answerCheckbox are actually coming from the form that I'm submitting to the controller.

```
val (currentQuesId, questionType, answerRadio, answerCheckBox) = runExamForm.bindFromRequest.get
```

And the form declaration looks like:

```
  val runExamForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "currentQuestionId" -> number,
      "questionType" -> text,
      "answerRadio" -> optional(number),
      "answerCheckbox" -> optional(list(number))
    )
  )
```

Comment: Your code looks okay to me.  If `questionType` is not `"CHECK_BOX"` or `"RADIO_BUTTON"` then you will end up with an empty List.

Comment: But when I try with a String like _BOX, it is not falling through and going to the case _ block but rather it throws an error.

Comment: Can you share a little more of your code?  I made guesses about the types of `answerCheckBox` and `answerRadio` and `questionType` but it would be better if you showed what they were.  Also, me testing with `"_BOX"` works okay; no errors.  I'm using Scala 2.10

Comment: What error does it throw when you use `_BOX` ?

Comment: Here is the error that I get: [MatchError: _BOX (of class java.lang.String)]

Comment: What is the type of `questionType`, i.e. can you try if `questionType.toString` works for you? Or alternatively can you convert this code to a function: `def getValues(questionType: <Type>)`?

Comment: questionType.toString also did not solve the problem. The questionType is already a java.lang.String type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is "equivalent" version of your code:

```
val selectedAnswers: List[Int] = questionType match {
  case "CHECK_BOX"    => answerCheckBox.toList.flatten
  case "RADIO_BUTTON" => answerRadio.toList
  case _ => List()
}
```

Does it work as expected?

Comment: If you see my original post above, answerCheckBox and asnwerRadio are optional types, I need to have an inner case block to fetch them or return an empty List.

Comment: So if it's an `Option` then it should have `toList` method. Please check if it works

Comment: I think a few clarifications would help regarding your question: 1) scala version, 2) types of all variables in this code snippet, 3) complete stack trace of an exception

Comment: Note that calling `.toList` on an `Option` will give you a `List` of either 0 or 1 elements.  This code is directly equivalent to the original posting.  The only change I would make is to use `Nil` in place of `List()`

Comment: I was suspecting that it's some weird type that implements `unapply` incorrectly but I can't even convince myself of that :). I don't understand the secrecy behind the types involved. Did it finally work?! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot, but try replacing the `_` with some other name (`x` is fine) and make sure that your code contains nothing but regular whitespace.

Very rarely I've seen bizarre errors like this caused by other non-printing characters in the code, which always seemed to be caused by pasting code from a chat on the OSX Skype client.

Also... Can you confirm in your code sample which line the `MatchError` occurs on?

Comment: If you look at the first original post and follow the source code, the error ouucrs in the line "case "CHECK_BOX"    => {"

Comment: and you can confirm that the code operates as expected if you pass in `"CHECK_BOX"` or `"RADIO_BUTTON"`?

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly fine when I pass in CHECK_BOX or RADIO_BUTTON.